Can a pre-fetched resource be used more than once?
This feels like a stupid question, but when I look at the network tab in the Chrome Dev Tools, it appears that the first time I use my pre-fetched resources I get a cache-hit, while the second time I get a cache-miss and the resources are re-transferred. An example of this below for two resources, 131.js and 6b87b67847fb32ad.module.wasm. The first time seems to used the pre-fetched value, however, the second access seems to request the resource again from the server

Am I understanding this correctly? If so, why wouldn't resources in the prefetch cache be used more than once?

Maybe something is different, try comparing everything in the details of each request.
